# send file then message through socket

Tags: java, file, sockets, message

I am trying to send a file from a client to a server. The server receives the file and then send a confirmation message to the client.

My problem is that the client becomes unresponsive when it is waiting the confirmation.

Server :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int port = 1234;
    ServerSocket server_socket;

    server_socket = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.out.println("Server waiting for client on port "
            + server_socket.getLocalPort());
    // server infinite loop
    while (true) {
        Socket socket = server_socket.accept();
        System.out.println("New connection accepted "
                + socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort());
    try {
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                int len = 0;
                int bytcount = 1024;
                String FileName = "C:\\test\\java\\tmp\\sentfile.pdf"; 
                FileOutputStream inFile = new FileOutputStream(FileName);
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream in2 = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024);
                while ((len = in2.read(b, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                    bytcount = bytcount + 1024;
                inFile.write(b, 0, len);
                }
                System.out.println("Bytes Writen : " + bytcount);

                //Sending the response back to the client.
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                oos.flush();
                oos.writeObject("ok");
                System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+"ok");

                in2.close();
                inFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file" + e);
        return;
    }
    socket.close();
    System.out.println("Connection closed by client");
        }
}
}
```

Client :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
        IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        int port = 1234;
    Socket socket = null;

    // connect to server
    socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);

    try {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(os, 1024);
            String file = "C:\\test\\java\\client\\source.pdf"; 
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            int i = 0;
            int bytecount = 1024;
            while ((i = in.read(buf, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                bytecount = bytecount + 1024;
            out.write(buf, 0, i);
            out.flush();
            }
            System.out.println("Bytes Sent :" + bytecount);

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String confirmation = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("from server : " + confirmation);

            out.close();
            in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    }
    socket.close();
}
}
```

Comment: May be you dont flush your outputstream from the server side? Do you see the message: `Message sent to the client is ok`?

Comment: going to comment on the uresponsive part. If the client is waiting for a response (reading response) then i guess it will be unresponsive. Have you considered making the request in a separate thread?

Comment: on the client side, it is blocked after "Bytes Sent:..".

if I comment the first part, it is working.
If I comment the second part, it is working.
Both, is not not working.

Comment: And on the server side, it is not writing "byte writen:...". But When the seconde part is comment, it is working perfectly.

Comment: Your code can't be compiled after simple copy/paste. If you want to get some help, add [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) style code here. Do not make us to do your routine.

Comment: I updated my first message with the full code.

Comment: You are sending over TCP. Confirmation is not required. Assume that the client has the file in one piece. Any problems are down to your own code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the complete working example. The server:

```
package so6540787;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

  private final Socket socket;

  public Server(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  public void receiveFile(File file) throws IOException {
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int len = 0;
    int bytcount = 1024;
    FileOutputStream inFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream in2 = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024);
    while ((len = in2.read(b, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
      bytcount = bytcount + 1024;
      inFile.write(b, 0, len);
    }
    System.out.println("Bytes Writen : " + bytcount);

    // Sending the response back to the client.
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    oos.flush();
    oos.writeObject("ok");
    System.out.println("Message sent to the client is " + "ok");

    in2.close();
    inFile.close();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket listen = new ServerSocket(10000, 1);
    Socket socket = listen.accept();
    Server server = new Server(socket);
    server.receiveFile(new File("c:/received.pdf"));
  }
}
```

And the client:

```
package so6540787;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

  private final Socket socket;

  public Client(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  public void sendFile(File file) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(os, 1024);
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    int i = 0;
    int bytecount = 1024;
    while ((i = in.read(buf, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
      bytecount = bytecount + 1024;
      out.write(buf, 0, i);
      out.flush();
    }
    socket.shutdownOutput(); /* important */
    System.out.println("Bytes Sent :" + bytecount);

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    ois.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    String confirmation = (String) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println("from server : " + confirmation);

    out.close();
    in.close();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Client client = new Client(new Socket("localhost", 10000));
    client.sendFile(new File("c:/tobesent.pdf"));
  }
}
```

The line you were missing is the "socket.shutdownOutput()". If you leave that line out, the server will never see the end-of-file marker `-1` from the `read` call.

Please fix the way you count the bytes that have been sent. You should really start with 0 instead of 1024 and only increment that counter by as many bytes as you have actually read.

Comment: Thank you. 
I was think it was something like that, clear the socket. I tried flush, reseet, close etc.

Comment: In its current form it is really redundant. But as soon as the server sends back some information (the file name under which the data has been stored, an error code if the disk was full), this protocol becomes very useful. For example, how would the client know that the last byte has been written successfully, if the server just closed the socket without sending `ok` first?

Comment: yeah that is just a part of the project. my server need to send other information to my client.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP! It's designed for exactly this type of problem. There are loads of HTTP client and server libraries freely available for Java.

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment?